# how to implement ItemDataBound in Nested Data Web Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I found this Article has a tutorial that i exactly needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510145.aspx

but i didn't understand how to Implement ItemDataBound event and what are these codes. does any one have any idea how to understand and implement these codes on ItemDataBound event.youtube link or some clear example ones...

Create an event handler for the CategoryList Repeaters ItemDataBound event with the following code:

```vb
Protected Sub CategoryList_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) _
Handles CategoryList.ItemDataBound
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem _
    OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

    ' Reference the CategoriesRow object being bound to this RepeaterItem
    Dim category As Northwind.CategoriesRow = _
        CType(CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row, _
            Northwind.CategoriesRow)

    ' Reference the ProductsByCategoryDataSource ObjectDataSource
    Dim ProductsByCategoryDataSource As ObjectDataSource = _
        CType(e.Item.FindControl("ProductsByCategoryDataSource"), _
            ObjectDataSource)

    ' Set the CategoryID Parameter value
    ProductsByCategoryDataSource.SelectParameters("CategoryID").DefaultValue = _
        category.CategoryID.ToString()
End If
End Sub
```

I Want to implement a nested repeater .this is my database model:

[image]

and My repeaters are here .I want to use Object data source to bind them to database. I need to have a list of startdate for each tour in nested repeater one.

```html
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSTTitle" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetById" TypeName="ATourRep">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Id" QueryStringField="CID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetById" TypeName="ATourDateRep">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>

<div class="container" id="TourDetail">

            <asp:Repeater ID="RptTourDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODSTTitle" ItemType="Tour" EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="RptTourDetail_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>



                        <img src="<%# Item.TImgUrl %>" alt="Alternate Text" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="row">


                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <%-- NestedRepeater --%>
                                <p>
                                    <%# Item.TourId %>

                                </p>
                                <asp:Repeater ItemType="TourDate" ID="RptTourNested" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <h2>
                                            <%-- What Should I write Here to have a list of each TourDate --%>
                                       <%# Item.TourStartDate %>
                                             </h2>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <%-- This Column works correctly --%>
                                <h4>
                                    <%# Item.TName %>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    <%# Item.TDes %>
                                </p>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-3">c</div>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

        </div>
```

Comment: You mean convert VB code to C#?

Comment: Yes I really need C# one @BikashSinghMaharjan

Comment: Here you go: Same article's [C# version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510144.aspx)

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan oh really really thank you 10000 times. it really helped. I have another simple stuid question because I'm New at asp.net. Is it possible for you to look at the article and tell me what is northwind which it is in ItemDataBound?

Comment: Northwind is a microsoft standard database, they often use for their examples. It can be downloaded somewhere

Comment: Northwind is the sample database from Microsoft, which you can download for free. For understanding Northwind in this specific tutorial, you'll have to jump back all the way up to the [Tutorial 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx).

Comment: Thank you really. i don't know how to vote for your help by comment. if there is any way to appreciate your help yell me please..I need read them completely because I want to use EFW model and I have no idea how to do it. . Thank you again any way . @BikashSinghMaharjan

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen  Thank you really.

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh, Glad to be your help. Good luck for your project :)